# How can I sort the sidebar alphabetically in sublime (ST2)?

Tags: sublimetext2

I see no option to sort the sidebar in Sublime, how can I do it? I'd like to sort it alphabetically.

Comment: do you mean the list of open files? That is in the order of the tabs, so you'd have to rearrange the tabs to sort the list.

Comment: @MattDMo yep quite right

Comment: I think many people use "Visual Studio Code" now, or otherwise, Atom.

Comment: Sublime is still very popular, and development continues on it. ST4 is in "private beta" right now - the most recent build was just released a few days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this answer

If you sort the tabs, it sorts the sidebar, and this sorts the tabs

I amended the classname though not to anything better. the classname was probably better before.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "sorttsortsidebar" }
```

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3876&start=20

```
import sublime_plugin
from os import path
from operator import itemgetter

# A simple command to sort current tabs alphabetically (returning focus to the 
# original tab).
# Does not work with different groups or windows. Not catered for unsaved views 
# (although it seems to work okay if there are any). It could be modified to 
# work in these circumstances.
#   { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "sort_tabs" },
class SorttsortsidebarCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
   def run(self):
      print("ddffd_sorttabs")
      file_views = []
      win = self.window
      curr_view = win.active_view()
      for vw in win.views():
         _, tail = path.split(vw.file_name() or path.sep)
         group, _ = win.get_view_index(vw)
         file_views.append((tail.lower(), vw, group))
      file_views.sort(key = itemgetter(2, 0))
      moving_index = 0
      for index, (_, vw, group) in enumerate(file_views):
         if index == 0 or group > prev_group:
            moving_index = 0
            prev_group = group
         else:
            moving_index += 1
         win.set_view_index(vw, group, moving_index)
      win.focus_view(curr_view)
```

Comment: how do you put this into sublime?

Comment: @Omar it was a long while back but look up how to write a really basic plugin e.g. one that inserts the text "hello world", then when have the code for that e.g. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin--net-22685  and you know how to install that(that link may help), then you could try to replace that with the code in my answer

Answer (score 9):

There is a Sublime [plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/) for that, called [SortTabs](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SortTabs). It works both with Sublime Text 2 and 3.

You can install it using `Sublime Package Manger` and then sort tabs using any of the following methods:

- Sort Tabs by file name
- Sort Tabs by file type
- Sort Tabs by file path
- Sort Tabs by modification date
- Sort Tabs by last activation

Comment: Installed the package manager through console, but I don't see any of the "Sort Tabs by..." option in the View menu. Is it supposed to be somewhere else? I'm on ST3.

Comment: @Manish You open ST drop down (Ctrl+Shift+P) and type `sort` - it will be there! ;)

Comment: This does not sort the folders, only the file names.